# UICollectionView NSIndexPath?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, nsindexpath

I have got the NSIndexPath from a uitableview before but I'm not sure why this doesn't work for collectionview? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here's the code I need to fix:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForSelectedRow];
sqlColumns *author = [self.favoriteExercises objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: What's not working?  What's `self.favoriteExercises`?  What's the `sqlColumns` class look like?  Where are you calling this code from?

Comment: no its the [self.collectionView indexPathForSelectedRow];

Comment: I asked 4 questions.  You answered none of them.

Comment: the line. [self.collectionView indexPathForSelectedRow]; is not working

Comment: How is it not working?  Not working means nothing.  Is it compiling?  It `indexPath` nil?  Is it throwing an exception?  Is it returning the wrong `indexPath`?  What are the actual results and what are the expected results?

Comment: @Robert, you have to use `indexPathsForSelectedItems` instead of `indexPathForSelectedRow`. This could return multiple selection items, thats why set the `allowsMultipleSelection` property in the `UICollectionView` to `NO`. Check my answer below mate

Comment: @nhgrif calm down buddy, you cannot expect a method to magically work if the method you speak of is not even implemented in apple's UICollectionView class library :P lol the `indexPathForSelectedRow` method is only available in the UITableView class. You have to use the `indexPathsForSelectedItems` method instead mate when it comes to collection views.

Comment: I'm not expecting it to work.  I'm not that familiar with collection views and wasn't aware that this didn't exist for them.  However, had Robert simple told us Xcode was telling him "No visible selector `indexPathForSelectedRow` for `UICollectionView`", it would've been helpful.  Besides that, it's just good question asking etiquette.  Explain what the expected result is and what the actual result is.  In programming, nothing just "doesn't work".  "Doesn't work" isn't descriptive or helpful in the slightest.

Comment: The question should include the feedback that Xcode is giving him (since he clearly doesn't understand what it means), and the correct answer (on top of pointing him toward the right method, which has been done), should include an explanation of what the "no visible selector" method Xcode would've been giving him means.

Comment: @nhgrif Yep I agree with what you have mentioned, there's also the case of to just be an epic coding guru and see all compile time errors as you `run` the code in your head ;) hehe

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just use `indexPathsForSelectedItems` in place of `indexPathsForSelectedRow`.
But this instruction will return more than one `indexPath` if you select more than one item. You should restrict the selection to one item by setting the `allowsMultipleSelection` of the `UICollectionView` to `NO`.

That said, Xcode has a brilliant autocompletion feature, you could have started to type "index" and it would have shown `indexPathsForSelectedItems` directly, you can also refer to the excellent documentation provided with Xcode. I Hope it will help you!

**UPDATE 1 - How to grab the indexPath from the array**

the `indexPathsForSelectedItems` method will return an array of NSIndexPath objects, each of which corresponds to a single selected item. If there are no selected items, this method returns an empty array.

Now to access this object, you have to ask yourself, how do I access an array? You do some research and then you will come to this conclusion:

```
NSArray *arrayOfIndexPaths = [self.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems];
NSIndexPath *indexPathImInterestedIn = [arrayOfIndexPaths firstObject];

//Voila
```

Comment: this dosen't work for my case because indexPathsForSelectedItems returns array, different pointer types to NSIndexPath

Comment: @RobertSaunders, thats exactly what it is supposed to do ;) Have a look at my update :)

Comment: Call `firstObject` on the array.

Comment: Nice one @nhgrif ;) hehe

Comment: @nhgrif could you give and example?

Comment: @RobertSaunders Pavan updated the answer to include the `firstObject` call on the array.

Answer (score 1):

There is no method `indexPathForSelectedRow:` in collection views because collection views are not limited to rows. You can have rows, columns, circles, spirals, rows **AND** columns, or an almost limitless list of different ways to arrange cells.

Do a search in the UICollectionView class reference for methods who's names begin with "indexPath".

The closest match is probably:

indexPathsForSelectedItems:

That method works for single or multiple selections. It returns an array of indexPaths instead of a single indexPath (much like the table view method indexPathsForSelectedRows for table views that support multiple selections).

There are also methods `indexPathForCell:`, `indexPathForItemAtPoint:`, and `indexPathsForVisibleItems`.